# jQuery to load partial view from jQuery

Tags: jquery, partial-views

I am trying to load a partial view from a jQuery. I have a Controller and index Action Action result. Index a C# HTML file.

Code written on index C# HTML file is:

```
 @section PViewsMenu {
    @Html.Partial("_menu")
```

}

```
<div id="mainContent" ></div>
```

Now I have a `menu.js` which is getting called from `menu.cshtml`. On `menu.cshtml` I have a button:

```
  <button style="float:left" data-bind="click: function (data, event) {$parent.load(data, event); return true;}">
                <span data-bind=""></span>
            </button>
```

On `menu.js` I have a method:

```
 load = function (data,event) {
               //event.preventDefault();
          $('#mainContent').load("../Product/_productList") // this line is not working probably.
```

However `_productList` is a partial view under `Product` folder and `_productList cshtml` is bound with `ProductList.JS` file.

Error:

> failed to load the resource.

Comment: try $('#mainContent').load(@Url.Content("../Product/_productList"))

Comment: throwing error :- invalid character for @

Comment: save path in hidden filed  

<input id="hdnUrl" type="hidden" value='@Url.Conten("Product/_productList")' />

//in js code

$('#mainContent').load($("#hdnUrl").val())

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('#mainContent').load('../Product/_productList');
```

But better way would be

```
$('#mainContent').load('@Url.Content("../Product/_productList")')
```

or another way

```
var $mainContent= $('#mainContent');


  $.get(url, function(data) {
        $mainContent.replaceWith(data);
    });
```

Also pay attention to the path.I am assuming it is correct.